# How to get a chat window on your page

Tags: facebook, chat

Hi just wanting to create a page for my diabetes group,
called type-1 crew, I want a little chat window to come up when the page is up.
How can I organise nice? I've seen it before?
cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SnapEngage](http://www.snapengage.com/).  Great product and simple to implement.